# Joint distribution of four random variables using Product Rule

Tags: probability, random-variables

I understand that the product rule of probability is

```
P(Y,Z) = P(Z) P(Y|Z)
```

Using the product rule, I try to find the joint probability of four random variables, and this is my solution.

```
P(W) P(Z) P(Y|Z) P(X|Y,Z,W)
= P(W) P(Y,Z) P(X|Y,Z,W)
= P(W) P(X,Y,Z|W)
= P(W,X,Y,Z)
```

Is this correct?

Comment: Quote:" This is my solution." What is the question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, in such situations you should use Cox theorem, which states that
$P(A,B|C) = P(A|B,C)P(B|C)$. So in your example one possible arrangement is

$P(X,Y,Z,W) = P(X,Y,Z|W)P(W) = P(X|Y,Z,W)P(Y,Z|W)P(W) = P(X|Y,Z,W)P(Y|Z,W)P(Z|W)P(W).$